# block ip address problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, block

Like others here, I'm having trouble blocking a range of IP address from my site. My .htaccess file:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 46.229.168/24
Deny from 5.9.63/24
Deny from 216.244.66/24

BrowserMatchNoCase SemrushBot bad_bot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

With these lines in place, over 5000 bots still appear in the log. Examples:

```
46.229.168.68 - - [08/Feb/2018:21:55:37 -0600] "GET /index.php/calendar/year.listevents/2015/04/26/15 HTTP/1.1" 500 850 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.77 - - [08/Feb/2018:21:56:03 -0600] "GET /index.php/calendar/year.listevents/2011/6/07/7 HTTP/1.1" 500 850 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.70 - - [08/Feb/2018:21:56:12 -0600] "GET /index.php/component/jevents/day.listevents/2010/01/18/7?Itemid=5 HTTP/1.1" 500 850 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.77 - - [08/Feb/2018:21:56:12 -0600] "GET /index.php/calendar/year.listevents/2011/6/07/7 HTTP/1.1" 500 850 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
46.229.168.73 - - [08/Feb/2018:21:56:26 -0600] "GET /index.php/component/jevents/day.listevents/2012/07/24/-?Itemid=5 HTTP/1.1" 500 850 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
4
```

I've noticed a couple of things about these lines from the log. They don't include the full name of the site. Could this be coming from inside the website and secondly, the "semrush" begins with a lower case letter.

I would appreciate any suggestions that would refine the lines in the htaccess file.

Comment: Are you sure they're not being blocked? Apache still logs the request even if there is an error. Guessing from the output of the logs, those 5 requests all returned a 500 error?

Comment: I don't know that. Is there a way I can tell?

Comment: Try checking your error logs to see why it says ` 500 850 `

Comment: They are being blocked, thus the 500 status.  Apache will report all blocks in the logs.  If you do not want to see it at all in Apache, you have to block it on the server (ex. IPChains) or before (firewall or WAF).